# Removing a primary key column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `master_employee` with a column `empid` as the primary key, and it has 12 rows in it. This `empid` has been mapped as a foreign key to another table named `dep_child`. I want to delete the 12 records in the `master_employee` table but I was unable to do it.

Comment: Because doing so causes problems for `dep_child`. You can either remove the FK, then do it or delete whats in dep_child first.

Comment: How to remove the FK in dep_child in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You were unable to do the deletes from `master_employees`, as there is a referential integrity with `dep_child`. You would need to either disable the constraint or delete the records from `dep_child`, before being able to delete records from `master_employees`

Comment: I had deleted all the rows in my dep_child table. Even then i was not able to delete my master_employee table records. can you tel me how to disable the constraint?

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename NOCHECK CONSTRAINT constraintname

Answer (score 0):

Add this constraints to your master_employee table

ALTER TABLE "master_employee"

ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_emp11"

FOREIGN KEY ("emp_id")

REFERENCES "dep_child" ("emp_id")

ON DELETE CASCADE;